# About photons and mirrors

Tags: photons, momentum, reflection, kinematics

If a photon hits a 'perfect' mirror (with no environment interference) would the mirror move a bit?

Comment: If a photon hits a perfect mirror that is fixed and rigid would the photon 'rebound' faster than if the mirror was not fixed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. Actually photons exert pressure on any surfaces exposed to them. For example, photons emitted by the Sun exert pressure of $9.08 \mu N/m^2$ on the Earth.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pressure

Comment: How much acceleration would that be, for example for a 1×1 meter square object with a mass of 1 gram in meters per second square?

Comment: @user1306322: Just use good old `F=ma` and of course force = pressure * area to work it out.

Comment: $a=\frac{F}{m}=\frac{9.08\mu N}{1g}=9.08\times 10^{-3} m/s$. That's a quite small acceleration so in order to build a practical spaceship powered by solar radiation, we need a quite large solar sail. In addition, this estimate doesn't consider solar wind but that's several orders of magnitude weaker.

Comment: Does a photon exerting pressure cause the photon itself to loose some energy in some fashion? Is any of the energy of a photon hitting a surface absorbed by the surface and if so does this deplete some of the photons energy? Is all the energy of a photon independent of its movements?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pressure#Radiation_pressure_by_particle_model:_photons

Answer (score 8):

Yes - you can even propel spaceships with it - [Solar Sail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail)

Although Solar radiation pressure at the Earth is around 9E-6N/m2 while the thrust from a Saturn V rocket is 34 MN, so you would need a solar sail something like 2000Km on a side to get the same acceleration