# Photon absorbed, identical Photon re-emitted

Tags: conservation-laws

I believe I frequently see it stated that a photon is absorbed and an identical photon is emitted.

How can the energy in equal the energy out, with no loss?

Comment: Energy is conserved.

Comment: my answer here may be relevant  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/503445/does-a-photons-wavelength-and-energy-change-when-reflecting-off-a-mirror/516959#516959  or here  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/248726/how-does-qed-explain-reflection/248741#248741 . has to do with center of mas versus lab considerations

Comment: It's not that reflected photon is _ideally_ the same as the input photon. Reflected photon [changes phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_phase_change) by $180^{\circ}$ and is partially (or [fully polarized](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/polref.html) if falls in a Brewster angle)

Comment: It's also worth noting that the outgoing photon can have less or more energy than the incident photon, e.g. due to interactions with molecular vibrations. See [Raman scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raman_scattering).

Comment: Please provide a reference source for your statement so we can explain under what conditions it's true -- or not true.   Example:  Electron absorbs photon and rises to a different orbital.  electron emits same photon and returns to original orbital.  But electron might emit a different photon and transit to a third orbital level.