# What does recoil kinetic energy of an atom mean?

Tags: energy, atoms, photon-emission

In the textbook I am reading for class it is talking about the interactions of photons with atoms and how when an atom emits a photon it must have the same and opposite momentum of the emitted photon. I am confused on what the book means by "the atom must also have a 'recoil' kinetic energy". [image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the atom gets momentum ($mv$) how does it not get kinetic energy ($0.5mv^{2}$) as well?

Comment: The recoil is the momentum m*v  the atom gets  and one needs it for the total momentum is always conserved

Answer (score 0):

A simple research gives several references of a recoil energy, it appears in another question appears in [a similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/653742/where-does-the-kinetic-energy-of-recoil-in-hydrogen-come-from), an electron is a particle and a photon is also a particle, their interaction should respect the conservation of the energy and the momentum (often ignored in this case). A simple case where the energy and the momentum are important : [absorption or emission of free electrons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/81448/can-a-free-particle-absorb-emit-photons).

In this case of free atoms, the effect depends on the mass of the atom, the photon momentum is given by $p_\lambda=E/c$ and this recoil kinetic energy is given by : $K=1/2 M_{at} (p_\lambda/M_{at})^2 = 1/2 E^2/(M_{at}c^2)$, $K$ is very weak and negligible especially for heavy atoms.